# Generate RESTful routes with dynamic prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes

I have an e-commerce web site written in Rails 3.2.8 which sells tickets for music events. So far I've been using simple RESTful routes in the application:

```
/ => default route: /events
/events
/events/1
/events/1/new
/events/2
...
```

All events used to happen in the same place, but from now on there's going to be two places, let's say "Morumbi" and "Maracanã". *Place* is a model in the application, and it's a very important distinction between the events. So I'd like to make the place name a part of the path, and have routes like this:

```
/ => default route: page to choose place
/morumbi => same as /morumbi/events
/morumbi/events/1
/morumbi/events/1/new
/maracana => same as /maracana/events
/maracana/events/2
...
```

Although I know how to do that using the `#match` method, I have already a good number of routes created with the much more maintainable `#resources` method, and I'd like to keep them.

Do you know a solution avoiding the use of `#match`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `#scope` method:

```
scope path: ':place_name', as: 'place' do
  resources :events
  ...
end
```

So `GET /morumbi/events/1` will call `EventsController#show` with parameters `id: '1'` and `place_name: 'morumbi'`.